# iOS streaming video error

Tags: ios, video, streaming

I get following error:

```
2012-04-04 23:46:18.374 istiqlaltv[17121:e903] -[istiqlaltvViewController moviePlayBackDidFinish]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6136ee0
2012-04-04 23:46:18.380 istiqlaltv[17121:e903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[istiqlaltvViewController moviePlayBackDidFinish]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6136ee0'
```

This is code, I am very new in iOS, I just want to play a streaming video when you press the play button.

```
-(void)playVideo{
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@"http://blabla.com/playlist.m3u8"];

NSString *strVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
float version = [strVersion floatValue];

if(version < 4.0){
    MPMoviePlayerController *themovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    themovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [themovie play];
}else{
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *themovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:themovie.moviePlayer];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:themovie];
}
}

-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    [player stop];
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `:` in the `moviePayBlackDidFinish:` selector when you add your observer:

Should be:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:themovie.moviePlayer];
```

Note that the colon after the method name indicates that the method takes a parameter.  You were getting the error because your code was looking for a method named moviePlaybackDidFinish that does not take a parameter, but no such method exists.